# Virtual host with XAMP and APPSERVER

Tags: apache, xampp, appserver

I have XAMPP and Appserver installed in one server (The first listens port 8080 and the second listens port 80).

I have a domain: example.com

I have this in APPSERV:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>  
    ServerName example.com  
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html  
    DocumentRoot "C:/appserv/www/folder"  
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way so I can send that request to port 8080?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of how I accomplished it with `ProxyPreserveHost`

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```